# Power BI - Averaging by group then removing outliers based on standard deviation

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, outliers, standard-deviation

I have a dataset that includes the following columns

Unique ID, Activity, Activity Duration

I was able to create a matrix that looks like this (I am not including the activity types for anonymity but the grouping themselves do not matter).

[image]

I looked into ways to filter out outliers and I came across this Calculated Column

```
CalculatedColumn = if([Column1]>PERCENTILE.INC(Table1[Column1],0.95),"Outlier", "Within 2 SDs")
```

This allowed me to create a slicer for my table. A user can come in, see the true data, then filter for those within 2 SDs. My concern is that this Calculated Column does not work by grouping, so the Max column for every activity is now 103. This does not reflect reality as activities vary in duration.

[image]

I am looking to create a slicer that would work dynamically by grouping. I cannot alter the original dataset to remove outliers since there are other tabs that require the full dataset. If I can create a Calculated Column or a Measure that would be best.

As a side note, this Calculated Column is capable of filtering out durations above 2 SDs but it does not seem capable of filtering out durations BELOW 2 SDs. If anyone has ideas on that, that would also be great!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, though, is to use FILTER() to create a "virtual" table of just the records you want... like this:

FILTER(Table1, [Column1]<=PERCENTILE.INC(Table1[Column1])

The thing to remember is that FILTER will return a subset of the columns in Table1. And it can evaluate measures and use those as filter criteria.
So the result will contain all the *columns* in Table1, just not the rows that don't meet the criteria specified. Then you can base whatever further calculations/measures on that.

Comment: Could you elaborate? This would be a measure correct? And Is there a way to address values less than the percentile? I found a -600 value that definitely is no use to us when discussing durations